# "tagged on for short bursts " in sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

The "tagged on for short bursts" in the sentence here:

> Anyway, groups of friends actually joined us for three-weeks stints
> and others just linked up with us.
> Some, whom we hadn't met before the trip at all,
> tagged on for short bursts
> --people from the area--who just came along for tide.

"tag on" in the dictionary:

> to add something to the end of something that already exists, especially in a careless way

"burst" in the dictionary:

> a sudden increase in something, especially for a short period.

What does it mean when two parts link together "tagged on for short bursts"?

Comment: "Came along for tide"? Do you mean _for the ride_? (NB A comma or full stop (period) should have a space after it but none before.)

Answer (score 0):

*[To tag on](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tag-on)* means to follow closely, to accompany, [to tag along](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tag-along).

[*for*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for) introduces a reason of them joining the group.

*short bursts* means short periods of intense, vigorous activity.

Comment: some people follow closely with sort of intense state in a short time ?

Comment: @showkey They went mountain climbing (an endeavour that requires a lot of energy and strength, which is usually done in short bursts with a lot of stops), some people joined them (tagged along) for a part of their journey.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko in this case, "for short bursts" clearly doesn't mean "for the purpose of short-duration intense activity". It clearly means "for short periods of time," even though I would agree that's not ideal wording for the desired meaning.